# What difference between costuming UITableViewCell in [self addSubview] and [self.contentview addSubView]?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I knew that Apple recommend developers to add subview in self.contentview, but What would happen if we add subviews in UITableViewCell?

Comment: Straight from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView): _"If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode"_

Answer (score 1):

after ios 7 [self addsubview] may not work,[self.contentview addsubview] is the best way to add subviews.
UITableViewCell has a scrollview
[you can read this](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/reproducing-the-ios-7-mail-apps-interface/)